# Cronjobs and Environmental Variables

Tags: cron

I have 2 versions of a site: Production and Dev.  The file system is:

```
/public_html
      production files.php
      more_production_files.php
      /dev
          dev_file.php
          etc...
```

Im setting up cron jobs, and I have environmental variables in the crontab to keep the paths correct for some of the PHP require() functions that are happening.

My question is, if I wanted to set up separate Dev and Production variables in the contab, can I do something like this?:

```
CRONTAB

# Dev Variables
ENVIRONMENT=/dev/
FULL_PATH=/home/username/public_html/dev/

# Dev Cron Jobs
0 0 1 1 1 php /home/username/public_html/dev/cronjob.php
0 0 1 2 2 php /home/username/public_html/dev/cronjob_2.php


# Production Variables
ENVIRONMENT=/
FULL_PATH=/home/username/public_html/

# Production Cron Jobs
0 0 1 1 1 php /home/username/public_html/cronjob.php
0 0 1 2 2 php /home/username/public_html/cronjob_2.php
```

When executing a Production cron job, would the 'Production Variables' above, replace the Dev ones?  Similarly, when executing a Dev cron job, would the 'Dev Variables' be used as opposed to the Production ones?

Comment: Normally, that works just fine, but to make sure, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Oops, missed your answer from before. Yes, it works on at least Ubuntu Linux which is what I'm running similar "constructions" on.

Comment: Great, yeah it does work.  Do you want to post it as an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to be running Linux, yes this works on most (at least recent) Linux distributions. For example, from the Ubuntu crontab(5) manual;

> An  active line in a crontab will be either an environment setting or a cron command.  The crontab file is parsed from top to  bottom,  so  any environment  settings  will affect only the cron commands below them in the file.